# Error manually regenerating .proto files

Tags: bash, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am trying to implement the stickynote application in this tutorial https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-compute-engine-grpc

However, when i try to manually regenerate my .proto files i get the following error message

> -bash: !ProtoCompiler/protoc: event not found

Here is the command i am trying to run on the command line

```
../Pods/!ProtoCompiler/protoc —plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=../Pods/!ProtoCompiler-gRPCPlugin/grpc_objective_c_plugin —objc_out=. —grpc_out=. -I . -I ../Pods/!ProtoCompiler *.proto
```

Not sure what the error could be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`!` is a special character in bash used for [History Expansion Event Designation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Event-Designators.html#Event-Designators)

Single quote your argument strings including it or escape using `\`

```
../Pods/\!ProtoCompiler/protoc —plugin=protoc-gen-grpc='../Pods/!ProtoCompiler-gRPCPlugin/grpc_objective_c_plugin' —objc_out=. —grpc_out=. -I . -I '../Pods/!ProtoCompiler' *.proto
```

Even better, rename the directory/binaries so that they don't have `!` in them.